# Story in which lemurs bred ancient hominids as labor animals and hunting animals

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a story about a paleontologist. Lemurs breed ancient hominids as labor animals and hunting animals. The hominids become intelligent and wipe out their lemur masters, so the lemurs are responsible for evolution of homo sapiens. It was a female author and possibly Russian. It was in an anthology like Years Best Science Fiction or Writers of the Future or something like that.

The title may be something like "Blunt teeth, bad taste" or "Short claws, dull teeth". I've looked for years and can't find it.

Answer (score 5):

It could be [**The last lemur (Последний лемур)**](https://www.libfox.ru/243649-50-aleksandr-kolpakov-sbornik-posledniy-lemur.html#book) by Alex Kolpakov (story is a part of anthology)

Plot: kind of traveling back in time to do scientific research.

> ...The black lemur was the first to jump out of the forest. He was not
> afraid of anything, and his brothers, obeying his call, rushed after
> him. "The naked must die, we will kill them," thought the leader, and
> his thoughts were clearly perceived by the consciousness of the
> researchers. - The green island belongs to us ... We lived here even
> before the great southern continent was flooded with Big Water ... "

[image]

Comment: This story is by acfemale writer with degree in paleo-anthropolgy and is written from perspective of lead scientist on a top secret dig that uncovers 300,000 yr old lemuridae settlement. The evidence proves lemeur ancestors bred primates as domesticated animals who eventually became smarter than thier master and drove lemuridae sapiens to extinction.

Comment: @EricJohnson ok, please add this information to the initial question (using edit)